# Does Chrome Remote Desktop work through LAN aswell?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, remote-desktop, google-chrome-extensions

Assuming both my Client and Server are on the same LAN, would the connection for Chrome Remote Desktop go through the LAN only, or would it still travel through Google Servers thereby adding to the ping and adding to the perceived "lag"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The same question was asked on the [Google forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/nQgkhvsSc3E), with an employee responding that the connection is over LAN (except in a few rare cases), but the authentication is done through Google servers.

His full reply:

> To be clear, connections between your client and host are direct peer-to-peer.  Although the connection setup is mediated by Google servers, once it's established Google is no longer involved (except in very rare cases where we need to fall back and use a relay server).  So in cases where your client and host are on the same network, once the connection is made it's likely to perform better than one that has to traverse the public Internet.
>
> Chrome Remote Desktop uses an entirely different kind of protocol from RDP.  It uses a video feed instead of sending bitmaps or images, and includes other optimizations to make the experience much better than RDP in most instances.

Comment: The google employee said the connection is peer-to-peer. They did not say the connection is over LAN.

Comment: @Nick If it's peer-to-peer and both peers are on the same LAN (OP's context) then it means it's over LAN only. For the connection to go though the Internet in this context, you would need a third party relay/proxy and it wouldn't be peer-to-peer anymore.

Comment: Yeah... *IF* it is peer-to-peer and both peers are on the same LAN. That doesn't mean it is always LAN. That means it's LAN only in those specific cases.

Comment: Does this mean if both computers are on a LAN and internet access is removed from that LAN then the computers will stay connected?

Answer (score 4):

I have had the experience of using Remote Desktop over LAN.
But it needs internet for the initial authentication via the Google servers. After that it's a direct peer-to-peer connection. If the internet goes out, the connection is smartly shifted to LAN if possible.

It happened in my case: the connection was set up and working and then the internet went out. But, instead of the connection getting dropped, it changed its path to LAN and it became faster than ever (*Cheers to that*!).