# Chrome Remote Desktop in LAN environment

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, google-chrome-extensions, remote-access, chrome-remote-desktop

Is it possible to setup and use Chrome Remote Desktop in a LAN environment?  So you don't need to login to google or need a google account to use it?  i.e. use Chrome Remote Desktop in a LAN environment which has no internet connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, no, simply because Chrome Remote Desktop uses your google account for authentication, and there is no way to explicitly connect to a specific system by ip address. Having near zero configuration has its downsides.

You're better off using some flavour of vnc, rdp or nx inside a lan. CRD simply isn't the right tool for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Journeyman geek, there's no way to use CRD w/o authenticating with Google, or when there's no Internet connection at all.

However if there is an option to use a restricted proxy just for authentication (i.e. very limited Internet access just for this purpose), it may still be possible. See this [post by a Google specialist](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/nQgkhvsSc3E/37E81-rMWcEJ) on 4/16/13, [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/581116/does-chrome-remote-desktop-work-through-lan-aswell), [this answer on it](https://superuser.com/a/776122/239558).

My remaining question is: any way to **force** CRD to use LAN when both LAN and WAN are available? (In my case, I *must* use VPN for RD, for security reasons, and while my host's firewall does no block CRD traffic, I still need to channel the session through VPN. Or get fired... :)